# Kie Builder fails with Unable to resolve ObjectType

Tags: drools, builder, kie

Using the JBPM Business Central Workbench - Ver 7.52

How do I add the data object 'definitions' to a Kie Builder when dynamically compiling a GDST?

Create a simple data object:

```
package com.stackoverflow.question1;
/** This class was automatically generated by the data modeler tool. */
public class message implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private java.lang.String status;
    private java.lang.String name;
    private java.lang.String message;

    public message() {}
    public message(java.lang.String status, java.lang.String name,
            java.lang.String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.name = name;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public java.lang.String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
    public void setStatus(java.lang.String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public java.lang.String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(java.lang.String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public java.lang.String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }
    public void setMessage(java.lang.String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Create a GDST,looks like:

[image]

DRL Extracted from the GDST looks like :

```
package com.stackoverflow.question1;

//from row number: 1
//Name was null
rule "Row 1 MsgRules"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        MSG : message( name == null )
    then
        modify( MSG ) {
                setMessage( "Name was null" )
        }
end

//from row number: 2
//Name was not null
rule "Row 2 MsgRules"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        MSG : message( name != null )
    then
        modify( MSG ) {
                setMessage( "Name was not null" )
        }
end
```

Download the JAR and extract the contents of the KJAR:

[image]

Use 7-zip to extract the contents:

[image]

Use this code to build the GDST from scratch

```
public static KieContainer loadGdstIntoContainer( String gdstFileName) {
    logger.info("KieUtilities:loadKieContainer - Started");
    try {
        KieServices   kieServices   = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        
        //URL resource = KieUtilities.class.getClassLoader().getResource("BaseClaim.class");
        //kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newUrlResource(resource));
        
        kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("MsgRules.gdst"));
        KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
        kieBuilder.buildAll();
        if (kieBuilder.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Build Errors:\n" + kieBuilder.getResults().toString());
        }
        KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();
        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId());
        logger.info("KieUtilities:loadKieContainer - Finished");
        return kieContainer;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.info("KieUtilities:loadKieContainer - Failed");
        logger.info(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

How do I resolve this error:
Unable to resolve ObjectType 'message' : [Rule name='Row 1 MsgRules']

I have tried adding the following so the builder would find the data object class but that does not work.

```
URL resource = KieUtilities.class.getClassLoader().getResource("message.class");
kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newUrlResource(resource));
```

Comment: 'BaseClaim.class' won't help you with missing 'message.class'

Comment: Sorry, that was from a different test, same error. I have updated the question with the correct class name.